# Stripe JS: Status 200 OK, but payments don't show up in Stripe Payments Dashboard

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate Stripe JS to my React ecommerce project. I'm currently able to see logs of the API calls successfully (Status 200 OK), but nothing is showing up in the Payments dashboard. Do you know what I need to do to see the Payments dashboard get updated?

To note, I know I'm not currently passing shipping and product details/totals. I'm assuming that any payment/product order details would show up as "null" in the payments dashboard, but I will fix this as the next step.

**server.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const postCharge = require('./stripe')
require('dotenv').config()

const app = express()
const router = express.Router()
const port = process.env.PORT || 7000

router.post('/stripe/charge', postCharge)
router.all('*', (_, res) =>
  res.json({ message: 'please make a POST request to /stripe/charge' })
)
app.use((_, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  )
  next()
})
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use('/api', router)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build')))

app.get('*', (_, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/index.html'))
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server running on port ${port}`))
```

**stripe.js**

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('<MY_SECRET_KEY>')

async function postCharge(req, res) {
  try {
    const { amount, source, receipt_email } = req.body

    const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
      amount,
      currency: 'usd',
      source,
      receipt_email
    })

    if (!charge) throw new Error('charge unsuccessful')

    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'charge posted successfully',
      charge
    })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: error.message
    })
  }
}

module.exports = postCharge
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "parcel build public/index.html --out-dir build --no-source-maps",
    "dev": "node src/server.js & parcel public/index.html",
    "start": "node src/server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "stripe": "^8.135.0"
  }
}
```

**CheckoutForm.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import {
  CardNumberElement,
  CardExpiryElement,
  CardCVCElement,
  injectStripe
} from 'react-stripe-elements'
import axios from 'axios'
import './CheckoutForm.scss'

const CheckoutForm = ({ selectedProduct, stripe, history }) => {
  if (selectedProduct === null) history.push('/')

  const [receiptUrl, setReceiptUrl] = useState('')

  const handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const { token } = await stripe.createToken()

    // const order = await axios.post('http://localhost:7000/api/stripe/charge', {
    //   amount: selectedProduct.price.toString().replace('.', ''),
    //   source: token.id,
    //   receipt_email: 'customer@example.com'
    // })

    const order = await axios.post('http://localhost:7000/api/stripe/charge', {
      amount: 200,
      source: token.id,
      receipt_email: 'customer@example.com'
    })

    if (receiptUrl) {
    return (
      <div className="success">
        <h2>Payment Successful!</h2>
        <a href={receiptUrl}>View Receipt</a>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
  <div className="checkout-form">
    <p>Amount: ${selectedProduct.price}</p>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Card details
        <CardNumberElement />
      </label>
      <label>
        Expiration date
        <CardExpiryElement />
      </label>
      <label>
        CVC
        <CardCVCElement />
      </label>
      <button type="submit" className="order-button">
        Pay
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
)
}

export default injectStripe(CheckoutForm)
```

**Response data screenshot when I click "Pay"**
[image]

Comment: Make sure you're not looking inside your live Stripe account, because the transaction is a test as is made clear by `livemode: false`.

Comment: I think some things are missing from your code you put in your question. The code shows you trying to use the Sources + Charge API, however that console log shows you creating a PaymentMethod. `stripe.createToken` wouldn't create a PaymentMethod, meaning you likely have some rogue code somewhere that's doing something unexpected.